# I’m uncertain the OFFICE365 REST API will work with exchange

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I have few questions regarding EWS Managed API and Office 365.

I am sure that EWS Managed API will work with Exchange Server 2013 but I am uncertain the OFFICE 365 REST API will work with Exchange.

Please help me out in this Issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 uses Exchange, so yes the Outlook REST API (and Graph) will work with Exchange data.  However, these APIs cannot be used with on-prem Exchange servers - they must always be used in the context of an Office 365 subscription/mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I have seen recently couple of posts in Microsoft blogs and in some articles that these APIs can use with Exchange 2016 CU 3. Here is the links: [On-Premises Architectural Requirements for the REST API](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/) and [Office 365 integration with on-premises environments](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-integration-with-on-premises-environments-263faf8d-aa21-428b-aed3-2021837a4b65?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: Yes, good find! Requires a hybrid implementation though, so still a dependency on Office 365

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your response once again. But I have a requirement with Exchange 2013 and curious about to know by any chance these Calendar REST API support working with On-Prem Exchange 2013.? If not Is there any other Microsoft API to handle this situation (I have referred many online blogs but I didn't find any proper documentation/ information).

Comment: Only a Microsoft employee can confirm whether they will open up the REST APIs for on-prem. You might be stuck with EWS for now

Comment: Yes, EWS can serve my requirements but it was very old one and my concern is, by any chance if it turns to deprecated API (Similar to Live SDK API) in coming days then it could be worst scenario for our developed application.

Comment: I doubt they'll deprecate EWS for a long long time

Comment: I came across this one. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ba-p/608055